# syslog not showing log levels in messages

Tags: log, logging, rsyslog

Here is sample output of my syslog messages in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Nov 15 20:20:48 ubuntu winbindd[915]: [2011/11/15 20:20:48.940063,  0] winbindd/idmap_tdb.c:287(idmap_tdb_open_db)
Nov 15 20:20:48 ubuntu winbindd[915]:   Upgrade of IDMAP_VERSION from -1 to 2 is not possible with incomplete configuration
```

How do I see what was the level of message, like info, warn, error etc.?

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS with rsyslog package version 5.8.1-1ubuntu2.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That is the default traditional format.

To output log levels in messages (technically known as *priorities*), you should change the default template used by `rsyslog`:

1. open with admin privileges the file `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and add the following lines

   ```
   $template precise,"%syslogpriority%,%syslogfacility%,%timegenerated%,%HOSTNAME%,%syslogtag%,%msg%\n"
   $ActionFileDefaultTemplate precise
   ```

   after the line

   ```
   $ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
   ```
2. restart the daemon, with the command:

   ```
   sudo service rsyslog restart
   ```

Now you should see lines like the following:

```
6,5,Nov 18 10:17:02,acer,rsyslogd:, [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.1" x-pid="7064" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
```

where the first two numbers (6 and 5) represent respectively the priority and the facility, where the priority is given by

```
7 - debug
6 - info
5 - notice
4 - warning, warn
3 - err, error
2 - crit, 
1 - alert, 
0 - emerg, panic
```

and the facilities can be seen in the `syslog(3)` man page.

Comment: More about formats in rsyslog docs: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_examples.html and http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_templates.html

Comment: @TahaJahangir the links are no longer working :(. Apparently, if you want some human-readable version of priority and facility, you can use `%pri-text%` which gives `local7.info` or `kern.log`